# Blue Screen of Death while formatting corrupted USB drive

Tags: windows, usb, bsod, formatting, flashing

I was trying to flash Linux Mint on my 32GB Sandisk USB Drive using BalenaEtcher.

But whenever I try to start flashing, my system crashes immediately with the following code on BSOD:

```
Stop code: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION 
What failed: CLASSPNP.SYS
```

Unfortunately, this also corrupted my USB Drive. I tried formatting using file explorer but it doesn't work.

[image]

I also tried using Diskpart in CMD as Administrator:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 3 
clean
```

But it crashes again immediately when I run `clean` with the exact same error code as above on BSOD.

How do I recover my USB Drive now?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro. OS Build:19043.2130 Version:21H1

Comment: "How do I recover my USB Drive now?" - You probably don't, since the reason for the original error, was the drive was faulty.

Comment: @Ramhound I had never flashed anything on it before, but it worked flawlessly for file storage before flashing